# Why MPI program is run faster in two PCs with 4 cores each compared to one PC while the number of processes are 4

Tags: ubuntu, mpi

I have read the documents and forums from internet. Many say that if number of processes are 4, then its will be assigned to each core which means one core will has only 1 process to run. Then i try to run the program with 4 processes in both single PC and two PCs environment. The result i got is two PCs is faster than one PC. Both of these environment also use 4 cores only but why two PCs are faster?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables to this, and you didn't give us much information to go on. How are the two PCs linked? What are their hardware specs? Are they busy besides running your program? How much work does your program do? Does it require a lot of CPU power/memory/disk access? Is there a lot of synchronization between processes? The list goes on.

One possible scenario is this: your one PC has 4 cores, but at least 1 of those cores is busy running the OS and other programs. So you only have 3, maybe 3 and a half cores to dedicate to your program, meaning one of your processes is constantly starved and possibly slowing the others down. Whereas the 2 PCs have 4 completely idle cores between them, so even with the overhead of network communication, they finish faster.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences but that answered my question. Thanks. Besides that, is that all the number of processes have been assigned to a core will be executed simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of another probable scenarios:

1) Main memory data rate is finite.
If you use 4 MPI-processes per node, memory data rate may become a bottle neck.

2) Are you really sure, that your PC has 4 cores? A lot of Intel processor use [hyper threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) technology. So maybe you have 4 virtual cores with only 2 real cores. To check it see specifications for your CPU at http://ark.intel.com.